# how to create an id with 24 character

Tags: java, android

I need to generate this type of id.
5bd8dbfaf6e49e1a228b7d9e
5b904729e9439747b264a6cd

[{"success":{"objectId":"5b904729e9439747b264a6cd","clientId":"1536182023806"}}]

Comment: To clarify: all you need is a 24 character string of random characters from [0..9] and [a..z]?
Can you show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

You don't explain in your question if you need something specific (md5, random id, etc), if you need something random you could use this function

```
UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "").substring(0,23)
```

This will return a random code almost impossible to be duplicated (almost).

Now, if you need something unique you could use a md5 hashing, using a autonumeric value and passing to a md5 value but the length will be more than 24 characters so you would need to truncate this using the substring function

Comment: thanks for the response. It's not random in same way it's autoincrement. I found this id in a lot of api. as you see in the example it start with same character. there is others .
60a8e387f99f5e15bd98fbb3
609d1dd1f09e07232fd2ced4
60896681d75a6a7c3a18b0b3
60894487ebb6424f80fc7811
5fd653606a41a97eff9bbd37
5fd6549ac9058d4aa35a40f8
5fd65d5c05d8b64aaa0e2247

Answer (score 0):

I would look at Apache Commons [`RandomStringUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html). Code would look like this

```
RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(24)
```